# Permission of uploads folder and server files folder on dedicated server

Tags: file, security, permissions

I will be running a website on a dedicated server, where users will be allowed to upload files (I am not checking those files for viruses). 
 
Lets say the folders are like so - 
**parent_folder -> website (folder which contains server files) 

parent_folder -> uploads (folder which contains user uploads)**

Question. Will file permission on website folder as 750, and on uploads folder as 770 suffice?

(Note1: Owner - Root; Group - Apache; website is a social network)
(Note2: As Apache (www-data) will handle uploads, I believe 770 may be required in place of 740) 
(Note3: As Apache (www-data) will only need to read files in website folder, therefore 750) 
(Note4: Server will be maintained by a single user)

Comment: I'm afraid this question cannot be answered. One trivial piece of missing info is the owner and group of those directories, but it also depends on a lot of details, your threat model, risk appetite, etc. Without all this info: I can think of an application where this is good enough, and also one where it's not.

Comment: Added more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think whether it's good enough or not depends on what risk you are willing to take. For a basic protection, it may be good.

What you have to consider is what would happen if files are stolen either by an unauthenticated attacker, or I suppose there would be some kind of an access control and users would have access to their own files, in which case an obvious risk is a user being able to access others' files. How would it affect your website / business if this happened? Are you willing to take this risk? Who are the attackers you are trying to protect against? Opportunist script kiddies? Knowledgable attackers specifically targeting your site? Nationstate-level attacks? You have to answer these first.

The drawback of this solution is that any application *or* operating system level breach will most likely give access to all uploaded files of all users. Should your application be vulnerable to things like local file inclusion, directory traversal, even SQL injection with certain databases or a lot more vulnerabilities, your files can be downloaded. Whether you want to protect them more depends on your use case.

More secure options could be storing them on a separate server (some kind of a file repository), encrypting them with user-specific keys (and then key management and cryptography in general is a huge topic itself), you could implement mime-type identification with whitelists to only allow certain file types (this is a slightly different aspect), or you could even add end to end encryption to protect against yourself (operations staff), etc. You can go lengths in terms of protecting these files, if you want to, but it gets very complex very quickly.